# sql Get count of X that do not have a Specific Y value in Group by X, Y

Tags: mysql

In a given table, There are 2 important fields. One field is a foreign key like field, in this case, userID the other is a status field. the data types do not matter, but for the sake of simplicity, both are integers. Status field has a limited number of outputs, again for simplicity, a 0 or a 1. the foreign key can of course be any reasonable integer.

The following query would have up to 2 rows per userID, totaling the number of rows with each status

```
SELECT userID, Status, count(Status) as total FROM tbl Group by userID, Status
```

if run on an example table, it would look something like

```
userID    Status   total
1         0        5
1         1        2
2         1        2
4         0        6
```

For this Imaginary table, This means the user with ID 1 has 7 rows in this table, 5 of which are of status 0, while the other 2 are of status 1. user ID 2 has only 2 rows of status 1, user ID 3 has no rows in this table, and 4 has 6 of status 0.

How can one further refine this so that only rows with Status of 0 are returned, but Only when the userID does not have any rows with status 1. In the above case, the only row returned would be

```
userID    Status   total
4         0        6
```

Comment: I hate questions that expect us to infer a source data set from a result. I'm neither psychic nor particularly clever, so I consider it elitist.

Comment: @Strawberry why is it that when i ask to solve for x in the equation x + y = 2, people ask me what y is. As shown by the accepted answer, there is a way to solve this without knowing y, just like you can solve for x without knowing y in Algebra. Not every fact is required to answer a question. This question was a conceptual question, the concept matters, what it is used on does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a conditional `COUNT` to calculate how many 1's are in the group.

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae880/3)**

```
SELECT u.userID, u.Status, count(u.Status) as total 
FROM users u
JOIN (SELECT userID
      FROM users
      GROUP BY userID
      HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN Status = 1 THEN 1 
                        ELSE NULL
                   END) = 0
      ) f -- filter
   ON u.userID = f.userID
GROUP BY userID, Status;
```

`else null` is optional for better read, but can be removed

**OUTPUT**

```
| userID | Status | total |
|--------|--------|-------|
|      4 |      0 |     6 |
```

`SUM` also work.

```
 HAVING SUM(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: That works at removing all the rows that have status of 1, but not those that have status of 0 when the userID has a row with status 1.
it returns both the top and bottom rows in the first example table

Comment: mmmm . ... who is George?

Comment: you know, i do not know. Just something i heard somewhere on some tv show a long time ago. Maybe Seinfeld.